# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch for username but arguments are there

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-urls

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'for_user' with keyword arguments '{'username': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['questions/by/(?P<username>[-\\w]+)/$']
```

i'm getting a no reverse match error however from what i can tell, all the necessary things are there. I have the url which has the username argument which is being given from the html and is being saved into the model and expressed through the view.

im a still a django novice. all help is appreciated.

file structure

```
usertest - root
-->accounts - appname
-->questions - appname
  -->urls.py
  -->views.py
  -->model.py
templates
-->base.html
```

**urls.py**

```
    url(r'by/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', views.UserQuestions.as_view(), name="for_user"),
```

**base.html**

```
<nav class="navbar mynav" role="navigation" id="navbar">
            <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand mynav" href="{% url 'questions:all' %}">WebSiteIcon</a>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li>hello {{ question.user }}</li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'questions:create' %}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'questions:all' %}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'questions:for_user' username=question.user.username %}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Log out</a></li>
                        {% else %}
                              <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Log in</a></li>
                              <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}" class="btn btn-simple">Sign up</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <div class="container mycontent">
```

**model.py**

```
class Question(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_updated']
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="questions")
    question = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False) # unique=True,
    question_html = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    answer = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    answer_html = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default='')
    tags = TaggableManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
    # ^ to display an object in the Django admin site and
    # as the value inserted into a template when it displays an object.

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.question_html = misaka.html(self.question)
        self.answer_html = misaka.html(self.answer)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "questions:detail",
            kwargs={
                "slug": self.slug,
                "pk": self.pk,
                "username": self.user.username,

            }
        )
```

**views.py**

```
class UserQuestions(generic.ListView):
    model = models.Question
    template_name = "questions/user_question_list.html"



    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
            self.question_user = 
              User.objects.prefetch_related("questions").get(
                 username__iexact=self.kwargs.get("username")
            )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404
        else:
            return self.question_user.questions.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["question_user"] = self.question_user
        return context
```

Comment: You haven’t shown the full error message. If `username=question.user.username` is used in the url tag, where is `question` set? In a loop? Then show the loop. Is it really a good idea to include that url tag in your base template? That means that every view that uses `base.html` might throw an error if the template context isn’t correct.

Comment: question updated.

Comment: As I said, your url tag uses `username=question.user.username`, but I don't see you setting `question` anywhere.

Comment: @Alasdair i've updated my base.html again to show the full content of what i have. I dont understand what youre asking in regards to "is  'question' set in a loop?" from what i've understood from the tutorials i've followed, the html pulls question.user.username from my model in models.py or views.py. Could you please direct me to an example of what you mean?<br/><br/>

is there a better location to place this url? i was trying to do something similar to how stackoverflow has their 'user activity' button that is to the right of the search bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% url 'questions:for_user' username=question.user.username %}
```

For this url to work, you need `question` to be in the template context. That means your view should look something like:

```
def view_question(request):
    question = Question.objects.get(text="What is your name?")
    return render(request, "template.html", {'question': question})
```

The error message `with keyword arguments '{'username': ''}'` suggests that `question` is missing from the template context.

When I first saw your url tag, I wondered if you were trying to loop through all the questions in a queryset, for example:

```
{% for question in question_loop %}
    {% url 'questions:for_user' username=question.user.username %}
{% endfor %}
```

That's why I asked whether the url tag was in a loop.

Now that you've expanded your question, it sounds like you want the username of the logged in user. The [auth context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext) adds `user` to the template context, so you can use `user.username` to get the username.

```
{% url 'questions:for_user' username=user.username %}
```

However, your base template should probably handle users that are not logged in as well. You can add an if statement to avoid errors for anonymous users.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}    
    {% url 'questions:for_user' username=user.username %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! Its still a bit fuzzy for me on why I don't need the 'question' in 'question.user.username'. In my other urls I needed it for the 'slug=question.slug' and 'pk=question,pk' arguments. The even more odd part was that i was instructed to use it for the other tutorial i was following and it worked then.....so it seems to have a mind of its own. i'll read up more on the URL arguments and the auth context processor link you pointed me too. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried to explain this at the beginning of the answer. If you use `question` in other templates, then the view will include `question` in the template context (e.g. `{'question': question}`) in the example above.